# can't subtract long double form long double in C++

Tags: c++, double, long-integer, subtraction

Whenever I do subtraction from long double, I get incorrect answer

```
long double Runge(long double a, long double b, int m)
{
long double R;
R=(b-a)/((2^m)-1);
cout<<setprecision(16)<<R<<endl;
return(R);
}
```

For example, when a=0.53733 b=0.53736 m=2 i get R equal to -2.805572983821669e-006

Any ideas why this happen?

Comment: Maybe it's your xor `^` that was unintentional. Are you looking for `pow(base, exp)`?

Comment: Or if `m` is always positive, `1<<m`, since the base is 2.

Comment: even when I do simple subtraction b-a I get crazy answer...

Comment: @QED: what does “crazy” mean?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @irrelephant: That looks wrong, but even then `(2^m)-1` just ends up being -1, and dividing by that shouldn't suddenly make the difference (0.00003) smaller by a factor 10.693.

Comment: @QED: How are you _calling_ that function? Are you sure the inputs are what you think they are?

Comment: the inputs are right, don't mind "(2^m)-1", even if I do simple subtraction like R=(b-a) when a=0.53733 b=0.53736 I get R=2.805572983821669e-006

Comment: I would still like to know which compiler and linker you are using and exactly how you are calling the function. Are there any overloads of the function? Are you calling it from a different compilation unit?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, no overloads, I call function:
  cout<<Runge(0.53733,0.53736,2)<<endl;

Comment: Perhaps try `cout<<Runge(0.53733L, 0.53736L, 2)<<endl;`

Comment: I'm calling it [like this](http://ideone.com/nuV3o5) and getting a different `R`.

Comment: Same thing [here](http://codepad.org/fH7lj9rX). Edit: with setprecision(16) like [here](http://codepad.org/JdKKAvEj) the output is still correct. Namely `-2.999999999997449e-05`.

Comment: A quick read of [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) may explain what you're seeing, outside of the obvious error of how you're XOR'ing rather than `pow()`ing.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in a comment, the `^` operator doesn't do what you expect. It's actually the bitwise XOR operator, what you are looking for it the [`pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) function.